# Is it a good idea to use MaterialEditText within a TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am implementing a password field that displays the count of characters while the user types like ("3/8+"). This is provided by [MaterialEditText library](https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText).

I also want to allow the user to hide/show the password, and this is provided by [Android's TextInputLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html).

I am currently using both, but when I click on the eye icon, the error message of the EditText blinks once (probably because the error message should be handle at the TextInputLayout level, not the EditText level). Whatever this is caused by, it makes me wonder if it is a good idea to use MaterialEditText within a TextInputLayout.

I feel like TextInputLayout pushes a lot of responsibility outside of the EditText towards the TextInputLayout, which may cause conflicts with MaterialEditText.

Should I drop MaterielEditText in that situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always prefeer to use Android SDK components, and what you need is ok with:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:hint="@string/hint_name" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

You can add the eye component for working with this kind of EditText without problem.

You don't have to use another library for what you need. When you use another library, there are lots of possibility to have much bugs as using SDK component.

**Just use a Third Party Library when you really think that you need for your porpuse.**

Nice coding!

Comment: I need MaterialEditText to specify a minimal number of char to type, so that the error message is updated live with the current number of chars typed. I just found that TextInputLayout also provides this feature with `app:counterMaxLength` and `app:counterEnabled`attributes. This might be a solution, I will try it later.

Comment: Yes! Thats what I tried to explain to you. You don't need it for that reason. Let me know if it was helpful

Comment: @Lois, just let me know if it was helpful my answer and don't forget to mark it as a correct. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I won't upvote or accept it since it does not provide any concrete details. I know that I can add an eye component inside a TextInputLayout, and I know that I should not use 3rd party libs when I don't need them. The whole point of my question is to expose what may be incompatible between MaterialEditText and TextInputLayout, or to provide a solution to my problem without MaterialEditText.

Comment: @Lois, I've already answered you.  You should drop MaterialEditText  in that situation. those kind of library was helpful when the version of android sdk is old, but now is enough with TextInputLayout & EditText. Let me know if I can help you with another thing related with MaterialEditText